# Flutter firebase_message plugin setup errors

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I wanted to try out cloud messaging in my Flutter application, but I always run into errors, and I have not found a solution yet. I followed the steps stated here: [firebase_messaging](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/tree/master/packages/firebase_messaging)

If I follow the steps except the optional part with creating an Application.java file for background messages, and I send a test message from Firebase to the launched application, I get this error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create service io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FlutterFirebaseMessagingService: java.lang.RuntimeException: PluginRegistrantCallback is not set.
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:3577)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:200)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1689)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6806)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
E/AndroidRuntime(29468): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: PluginRegistrantCallback is not set.
   at io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FlutterFirebaseMessagingService.startBackgroundIsolate(FlutterFirebaseMessagingService.java:157)
   at io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FlutterFirebaseMessagingService.onCreate(FlutterFirebaseMessagingService.java:77)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:3565)
```

For me it seems like that the optional part is needed too, but when I do that I get errors when the app opens. After the errors the app still runs, and if I send a test message from Firebase the app receives it succesfully. Later it doesn't even receives the message, but thows the same errors.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.app.Application android.app.Activity.getApplication()' on a null object reference
   at com.github.adee42.keyboardvisibility.KeyboardVisibilityPlugin.registerWith(KeyboardVisibilityPlugin.java:107)
   at io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java:22)
   at io.flutter.plugins.Application.registerWith(Application.java:18)
   at io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FlutterFirebaseMessagingService.startBackgroundIsolate(FlutterFirebaseMessagingService.java:164)
   at io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FirebaseMessagingPlugin.onMethodCall(FirebaseMessagingPlugin.java:133)
   at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:222)
   at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.handleMessageFromDart(DartMessenger.java:96)
   at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.handlePlatformMessage(FlutterJNI.java:656)
   at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
   at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:326)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:165)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6806)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)

[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(error, Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.app.Application android.app.Activity.getApplication()' on a null object reference, null)
    StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:569:7)
    MethodChannel.invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:316:33)
    <asynchronous suspension>
    FirebaseMessaging.configure (package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart:118:16)
    main (package:vonatles/main.dart:18:22)
    _AsyncAwaitCompleter.start (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:43:6)
    main (package:vonatles/main.dart:12:10)
    _runMainZoned.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (dart:ui/hooks.dart:229:25)
    _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1124:13)
    _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1021:19)
    _runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1516:10)
    runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1500:12)
    _runMainZoned.<anonymous closure> (dart:ui/hooks.dart:221:5)
    _startIsolate.<anonymous closure> (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:305:19)
    _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:172:12)
```

**Versions:**

```
firebase_core: ^0.4.0+1  
firebase_database: 3.0.7  
firebase_messaging: 5.1.5 

classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'  
classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.0"  
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.0'
```

In the Flutter main function I have this:

```
final FirebaseMessaging _firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging();

_firebaseMessaging.configure(
  onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
    print("onMessage: $message");
  },
  onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
    print("onLaunch: $message");
  },
  onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
    print("onResume: $message");
  },
);
```

The Application.java code:

```
package io.flutter.plugins;

 import io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication;
 import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry;
 import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry.PluginRegistrantCallback;
 import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant;
 import io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FlutterFirebaseMessagingService;

 public class Application extends FlutterApplication implements PluginRegistrantCallback {
   @Override
   public void onCreate() {
     super.onCreate();
     FlutterFirebaseMessagingService.setPluginRegistrant(this);
   }

   @Override
   public void registerWith(PluginRegistry registry) {
     GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(registry);
   }
 }
```

My android main directory:

```
-main  
  -java  
    -io.flutter.plugins  
      Apllication.java  
      GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java  
  -kotlin  
    -my.package.name  
      MainActivity.kt
```

AndroidManifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="my.package.name">
    <application
        android:name="io.flutter.plugins.Application"
        android:label="mylabel"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            ...
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: have you added your Application class to AndroidManifest.xml ? if no then replace FlutterApplication with Applcation class you have created.

Comment: @HarishPenta I've added it to the manifest, but I'm not completely sure about that I did it correctly. I've appended the manifest to the post.

Comment: replace your Application class from **io.flutter.plugins** package into your kotlin **my.package.name** then  change the path of Application Class  in the AndroidManifest file, then let me know.

Comment: @HarishPenta I still get the NullPointerException error for Activity.getApplication(). But one more thing is, that if I set the onBackgroundMessage in the configuration as in the tutorial, it throws an error too ('NoSuchMethodError: The method 'toRawHandle' was called on null.')

Comment: did you set `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` in your build.gradle file? If so, then post a link to your app on GitHub & I'll take a look. To tell you what's wrong, I need to zoom out & see the entirety of your app - something's off with the "order of operations" somewhere.

Comment: @wooldridgetm I've tried it with a new project, and I stated here what I found: [Issue](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/145)

Comment: @B.G. I'm getting the same issue. Were you able to figure out the solution?

Comment: @heisenberg91 The github issue is still open about it. The problem is that some plugins are not okey with firebase_messaging in the android code part, in the registerWith functions. Here is that issue: https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/145

Answer (score 7):

Since my MainActivity in android was a Kotlin class, I got the solution to this problem when I tried the Application class as a Kotlin class instead of trying it as a Java class.
I tried many solutions, still, I was not able to run the app.

Application.kt

```
package YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME

import io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry.PluginRegistrantCallback
import io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FlutterFirebaseMessagingService

public class Application: FlutterApplication(), PluginRegistrantCallback {
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        FlutterFirebaseMessagingService.setPluginRegistrant(this)
    }

    override fun registerWith(registry: PluginRegistry) {
        FirebaseCloudMessagingPluginRegistrant.registerWith(registry)
    }
}
```

Also, FirebaseCloudMessagingPluginRegistrant.kt

```
package YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME

import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry
import io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FirebaseMessagingPlugin

class FirebaseCloudMessagingPluginRegistrant {
    companion object {
        fun registerWith(registry: PluginRegistry) {
            if (alreadyRegisteredWith(registry)) {
                return;
            }
            FirebaseMessagingPlugin.registerWith(registry.registrarFor("io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FirebaseMessagingPlugin"))
        }

        fun alreadyRegisteredWith(registry: PluginRegistry): Boolean {
            val key = FirebaseCloudMessagingPluginRegistrant::class.java.name
            if (registry.hasPlugin(key)) {
                return true
            }
            registry.registrarFor(key)
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

This can be added in the sample directory where your MainActivity is.

Try this Along with the steps mentioned here: [Firebase messaging](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging)

Comment: This is the only one that worked for me after hours of trying, thanks for the great info and answer :)

Answer (score 0):

by the way you can create a **notification_handler.dart**  like this [Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method 'toRawHandle' was called on null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57851184/unhandled-exception-nosuchmethoderror-the-method-torawhandle-was-called-on-n). 
i have posted my **notification_handler.dart** their. 
try to configure with that and just call is as below from your statefullWidget and the let me know.

```
   @override
    void initState() {
      super.initState();
      new NotificationHandler().initializeFcmNotification();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Background notification setup is not optional anymore. Make sure to follow [intructions](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging#optionally-handle-background-messages) properly. And i was confused in making change in AndroidManifest.xml, So i wanted to share clear instruction.
PluginRegistrantCallback is not set" means Application.java file is not called properly at AndroidManifest.xml. Make change as follows:

[First it looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JTDCl.png)

[Change it to yourpackagename.Application like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bbr7i.png)

If you get "Default activity not found" error, run "flutter clean" command in your project folder and run it again.

Answer (score 0):

In your AndroidManifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="my.package.name">
<application
    android:name=".Application" //edit this line
    android:label="mylabel"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        ...
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```